# Add Fee or Discount to Order Totals - Problem with Order Confirmation Email

Tags: magento-enterprise, discount

I am finding difficulty in getting discount to order confirmation email template . I am working on enterprise version 1.12.0.2 . Discount label and price is not displaying in order confirmation email template though the grand total is correct. While the same code is working correctly if I put it in the Magento community version, its displaying both label and price. Please suggest me the what can be the error .

```
After Debugging
```

i found that sale_email_order_item observer is not calling

> To be more clear

Code is working correctly displaying the discount label and price in order , invoice but only not displaying in order confirmation email template